# Mi resolver de un Field en Graphql con laravel no funciona

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, graphql

Estoy tratando de realizar este resolver personalizado para un campo, he usado antes graphql en Node, y pero es la primera vez que lo uso con laravel, no entiendo aun por que mi resolver no funciona.

[image: Este es mi Type de Categoria]
[image: Aqui esta la definicion de mi resolver]

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre resolver el asunto. Debia retornar un objeto con el identificador del nombre del Type.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]